# Oracle SQL GROUP BY issues in sub query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by, subquery

I'm having issues getting my command to work and it seems that no matter what I do I continue to get an Oracle error on the SELECT customer_no statement.

It is always either a `Not a Group By` error, or a `Not a single-group group function` error.

The goal is to create a query that finds all the customers who have ordered styrofoam and with a defined size. For those customers, I also want to find their first and last styrofoam order.

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_no, MIN(date), MAX(date)
FROM    (SELECT customer_no, details, city, size, order_item, state, date
         FROM (((customer JOIN region USING (location)) JOIN order USING (order_no)) 
         JOIN rep USING (emp_no))
         WHERE order_item = 'Styrofoam' AND size IS NOT NULL
         GROUP BY details, size, date, city, order_item, state);
```

Comment: Why all the extra fields in subquery? You should not even need one. Also customer_no is not in group by and it looks like it should be.
Try: SELECT customer_no, MIN(date), MAX(date) FROM [..] WHERE [..] GROUP BY customer_no

Answer (score 2):

You have no `customer_no` in the `group by`.  This is causing the error.  But, why all the complication:

```
SELECT customer_no, MIN(date), MAX(date)
FROM  customer JOIN
      region
      USING (location) JOIN
      order
      USING (order_no) JOIN
      rep USING (emp_no)
WHERE order_item = 'Styrofoam' AND size IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY customer_no;
```

The names of the tables suggest that all the joins are not necessary.  For instance, none of the columns obviously would come from a table called `rep`.